# Почему использование configChanges считается плохим тоном?

Tags: java, android

Есть МП которое должно работать и работает только в портретном режиме.
Могу ли я беззаботно объявить в манифесте

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

для избежания пересоздания `Activity` в достаточно редком, но неприятном кейсе:

Пользователь выключает экран устройства на текущем `Activity`, меняет ориентацию и включает.

Судя по https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html и другим ресурсам этого лучше избегать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этого лучше избегать по тому, что view не пересоздастся с использованием нужного qualifier (layuot-land и т.д.). Если вы точно знаете что у вас все ресурсы одинаковые для разных ориентацией, то можно спокойно использовать `configChanges`. Бывают нестандартные ситуации, когда без этого никак.

Однако если у вас приложение работает только в портрете, то можно задать в манифесте

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

И не переживать по поводу поворота экрана.

Comment: в том то и дело что прописано. Но вот в чем беда - при включении устройства в непортретном режиме все равно происходит пересоздание и перерисовка activity/fragment

Comment: @abbath0767 Мне кажется тут ключевой момент что пользователь **выключает экран устройства**. Все же система не гарантирует что ваша `Activity` не убьется при включении/выключении экрана и при сворачивании/разворачивании приложения. Не уверен что configChanges должен в этом как-то помочь.

Comment: Кстати, проверил у себя. На мощном девайсе без флага don't keep activities активность не пересоздается без configChanges, но это не значит что она не будет пересоздаваться всегда. Зависит от мощьности девайса, длительности выключения и т.д. Cистема сама принимает решение о прибивании или не прибивании актовностей.

Comment: спасибо за комментарий, не знал что это зависит от железа устройства. Наверное вы правы и будем работать со стандартными методами. Правда все равно не понимаю почему при добавлении этого флага в проект проблемы не воспроизводятся и не требуется дополнительная обработка изменения конфигурации устройства (закомментив все saveRetainInstance методы ничего не упало и работало будто activity не пересоздается, как и все внутренние fragmet'ы)